# Parallax mode is not working in collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am setting the collapsing toolbar layout. I have set the parallax mode for the relative layout below the toolbar.

But it dose not get fade when I scroll the toolbar up. I just shows the relative layout above the toolbar's title. It get's merged with the toolbar.

Have  set all the modes still it's getting merged.

Layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Event Name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/eventName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PLAN"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Schedule"
                android:id="@+id/schedule"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Check List"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Vendors"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Invitee"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />
        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

looks like this after scrolling up :

[image]

What's wrong?

Please help Thank you..

Comment: Add _CoordinatorLayout_ as your parent layout.

Comment: Can you share screen.

Comment: I have added the coordinator layout as parent layout, don't know why it is not getting post @PiyushGupta

Comment: Check this link http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

Comment: Please check added screen . @jaydroider

Comment: @user6265109 Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try to remove `enterAlways` from your `Relative Layout`.

**`Only use this.`**

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">
```

> For **e.g** You `Layout` `ToolBar` Should be Below `Relative Layout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: got it. I have added toolbar above the relative layout should be below the layout. @jaydroider

Comment: Yes it should below the `Tool Bar Layout`.

Comment: @user6265109 Edited my answer pls refer that.

Comment: @user6265109 If it worked then accept and up-vote the answer so question will be closed.

Answer (score -1):

Put below line in your Relative layout:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```